# Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Unknown datum type org.joda.time.DateTime:

Tags: avro, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-schema-registry

The following field is causing my Kafka Stream application to fail when it tries to produce message.

```
{
    "name" : "TS",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "long",
      "logicalType" : "timestamp-millis"
    },
    "doc" : "date time indicating the timestamp of the position (in UTC)"
  }
```

Below is the stack trace when the Stream tries to write the message to output topic

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Unknown datum type org.joda.time.DateTime: 2018-02-12T06:14:37.000+05:00
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.getSchemaName(GenericData.java:772)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData.getSchemaName(SpecificData.java:302)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.resolveUnion(GenericData.java:737)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.resolveUnion(GenericDatumWriter.java:205)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:123)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter.writeField(SpecificDatumWriter.java:87)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord(GenericDatumWriter.java:156)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:118)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:75)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:62)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:101)
```

The Serdes used to produce the message is instanitated as

```
final Map<String, String> serdeConfig = Collections.singletonMap(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG,"http://localhost:8081/");

final Serde<GenericRecord> valueGenericAvroSerde = new GenericAvroSerde();
        valueGenericAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false); // `false` for record values
```

Comment: Not sure. Seems to be an AVRO issue, not a Kafka Streams issue. If found: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1891 -- could it be related?